# Changing commit comment not possible

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I've made a commit on SVN Tortoise, but I have a problem. I want to change the comment that I did, but when I try to do it I get this error:

> Subversion reported an error: While handling the 'svn:log' property on
>   '/svn/tigers-code/!svn/bln/16': Repository has not been enabled to
>   accept revision propchanges; ask the administrator to create a
>   pre-revprop-change-hook`

I use redmine for university and I update commits here.

Answer (score 1):

As the error says: `Repository has not been enabled to accept revision propchanges`. So you are not allowed to change the commit comment.

So follow the advice there: `ask the administrator to create a pre-revprop-change-hook`